# How to redirect to previous page after a form save in cakephp?

Tags: php, url, cakephp, parameters

I have two pages: `bookings/index` and `users/myUserAccount` that have a link to `locations/add`.
What I want is that after I save the form for `locations/add` I want to go back to the page that refered this one. If I am in myUserAccount, click `locations/add`, I complete the form, save my location and I want to go back to myUserAccount. What would it be a good solution to do this? I tried with cakephp's function `$this->referer()`. When I get in `locations/add` page the referer shows me the last page, but when I press save it has to go again through my add action from location controller and my referer changes now to `locations/add`.

Comment: save the previous one in session and then redirect to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store your referer in a session variable the firt time you arrive in your `locationsController->view()` and retrieving it when you actually pass data to the controller

or you can pass a parameter in your link to decide whether your are coming from `users/myUserAccount` or from `bookings/index` i.e.

```
locations/add/referer:user
```

or

```
locations/add/referer:bookings
```

Comment: And this will redirect to last Page
$this->redirect($this->referer());